# Migrating one (addon) domain from an account in Cpanel

Tags: domain, hosting, migration

I'm looking for a best solution to make migration for domain (let's call it 2.com) that is addon domain to an account hosted with Cpanel. 
Situation is this - user has one hosting account on WHM/Cpanel server that is created and bound with domain 1.com as a main domain. 
After few years, he adds new domain - 2.com as addon domain to that account. 
On the next year, he does not pay for 1.com and continue to use 2.com in his account.

What is the elegant and hassle free way to make migration of 2.com to a new cpanel server ?
Is there is an easy way to swap the domains and 2.com to become main domain for this account ?

I'm waiting for your solutions.
Nikolay Kabaivanov

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a process described in the cPanel forums for extracting an addon domain to it's own account: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/best-way-move-addon-domain-out-its-own-account-124025.html

Unfortunately it doesn't look like an automated process. There has been requests to create a script but as yet there is no planned schedule for completion: http://forums.cpanel.net/f145/tool-migrate-addon-its-own-full-account-please-case-8970-a-157953.html

Comment: As Cpanel admins says "This is not planned to be part of 11.32 (whose feature set has essentially been frozen in preparation for release), 11.34 nor 11.36. This puts the anticipated ETA beyond the end of calendar year 2011."